# Sorting custom fields in wordpress doesn't work when two many records

Tags: wordpress, sorting, custom-fields

I'm making a website to sell properties. I use wordpress with wp-property plugging. My db contains around 2000 properties.
On my macbook (localhost), everything is working fine. But online, I have the following problem : when there are a large amount of properties matching the search criteria (i.e. more than 500), I can only sort the found properties according to the post title. If I try to sort them according to any of the custom fields I created (price, area,zip code...), I get the message "no properties found" and all properties which were shown disappear. If the amount of property is low, it works...
I guess that this problem could come from some parameter... Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

the thing that is limiting your results is php/apache `max_input_vars` setting on your hosting provider .. you can try to contact them and ask if they can increase that limit for you (the default limit is 1000) or you could try to create `php.ini` in your web root and enter higher limit number like:

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```

or you can create `.htaccess` with this content:

```
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I created a php.ini file and copied into the web root with FileZilla, but I still face the same issue. Tomorrow, I will call my host provider (it is 1am now in France).  BTW, the default limit doesn't apply to post titles and only to custom fields ?

Comment: I updated my post with .htaccess file method,, see if that works, if not I think you'll have to send request to your support from hosting firm :|

Comment: In the website directory, I have the following .htaccess file : 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress                      Can I add the line you wrote just before the last line of the file ?

Comment: I would suggest to enter that line as first line, just before # BEGIN. .. and see if that solved it,, and if not, just remove it

Comment: you can try to see if this setting works,, `max_input_vars = 2000` just add = sign and save,, see if that removed the error,, if not, I give up :|